Towards Schauder estimates: smoothing effect of the semi-group generated by $\Delta+(-\Delta)^{1/2}$
Consider the semi-group $(P_r)_r$ generated by $\Delta+(-\Delta)^{1/2}:$ for a distribution $f$ let $P_rf:=p(r,\cdot)*f$ where $p(r,x):=\sum_{q \in \mathbb{Z}^d}e^{2\pi\mathrm{i}\langle q,x\rangle}e^{-r(|q|^2-|q|)}.$
A well known fact for the heat semi-group generated by $\Delta(H_r:=e^{r\Delta})$ is for ever $\delta>0$ there exists $c$ such that for every $\alpha$, every distribution $f,$ $$\left\Vert H_rf\right\Vert_{\alpha+\delta}\leq c r^{-\delta/2}\left\Vert 
 f\right\Vert_{\alpha}$$ (See Lemma 2.8. here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00692 which relies on a decomposition of "homogeneous" functions Lemma 5.5 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5113)
is it possible to derive a similar estimate for $(P_r)$? (we can note that $p$ doesn't fall within the above Lemma 5.5. Going through every detail in the proofs it seems one constant (there is another one depending on $\delta$) would be $c(r)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i\langle x,y\rangle}e^{-|y|^2+r^{1/2}|y|}dy|dx$, can we bound it uniformly in $r$? If not on an interval $[0,U]$?

Yes, just view the second bit as a perturbation and apply Duhamel.

Hi, kindly can you elaborate? Do you mean to redefine the heat semi-group so that $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ is excluded or?
